# Getting Fatal error -- Class 'app\modells\Country' not found

Tags: php, yii2

Following the guide in http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2-guide.pdf#lstnumber.-289.1 , I am getting the error below (pg 36).

I had mistyped

```
use app\models\Country;
```

to

```
use app\modells\Country;
```

in that controller, but after correcting it, I am still getting the same error. Besides the debugging locations `runtime/debug/56484c0c8c498.data:`, I could not find anywhere that word is used.

Perhaps its related to cache ? How should I clear it ?

[image]

**Update**

The url I am using : `http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=country/index`

File

```
basic/models/Country.php
```

contains

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Country extends ActiveRecord
{
}
```

Comment: Are you totally sure that `app/models/Country.php` is located under  `namespace app\models;` ? Yii2 follows PSR-4, so that shouldn't be caching issue

Comment: @dave Hmm, I do not have `app` directory. Everything is under `basic` directory. This is the project I'm using -- https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic

Comment: OK. Have you created `basic/models/Country.php` manually or you used a Gii to generate it?

Comment: I created it manually.

Comment: Can you post its source here?

Comment: And what if you replace that fatal line with `$query = \app\models\Country::find();`

Comment: Well, yea, it worked. I had to restart apache to clear cache. Thanks a lot. :-)

Comment: The issue is not related to Yii at all. You have an issue with Apache configuration somewhere. Can't you simply download and install something like WAMP/LAMP?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95180/discussion-between-maan81-and-dave).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your framework is caching the code. Try [clearing the Yii cache](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/console-clearcache-and-assets/) with `./protected/yiic clearcache cache`.

If you have APC running you may also need to restart the service.

Caching is very useful in a production environment but not really needed for development. You could disable it locally as you work.

Comment: He's using Yii 2, not 1.1

Answer (score 0):

In Yii2 I think you could clear (delete) runtime directory

```
yourApp/runtime
```

try remove this dir and then restart your app